# change Vaadin grid/table orientation

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7, vaadin-grid

How should I change the orientation of table or a grid? I want the headers to be on the left hand-side. Just 2 columns with header on the left side and value on the right side.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot achieve such functionality with Table, but you can use Frozen Columns feature of Grid to emulate columns as first cells in each row like here http://demo.vaadin.com/sampler/#ui/grids-and-trees/grid/features